# Excel looking to flag dups based on another column

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the best excel formula for the sample data in yellow. Where there are multiple different dates for the same account, then i would like to populate Yes for "has multiple"

[image]

Comment: Try using IF and COUNTIFS: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)>0,"Yes","No")`.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2),"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 0):

Answer : =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)>0,"Yes","No"). Thanks @BigBen and @Scott Craner

Comment: You do not need the `>0` if it is `0` it acts like false and any positive number acts like true.  It can stay, just an FYI